# I add nodes(10 nodes) but cassandra-stress result is slower than single node?

Tags: cassandra

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.170.128  317.66 MiB  256          62.4%             45e953bd-5cca-44d9-ba26-99e0db28398d  rack1
UN  192.168.170.129  527.05 MiB  256          60.2%             e0d2faec-9714-49cf-af71-bfe2f2fb0783  rack1
UN  192.168.170.130  669.08 MiB  256          60.6%             eaa1e39b-2256-4821-bbc8-39e47debf5e8  rack1
UN  192.168.170.132  537.11 MiB  256          60.0%             126e151f-92bc-4197-8007-247e385be0a6  rack1
UN  192.168.170.133  417.6 MiB  256          56.8%             2eb9dd83-ab44-456c-be69-6cead1b5d1fd  rack1
Datacenter: dc2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.170.136  386.12 MiB  256          41.0%             2e57fac6-95db-4dc3-88f7-936cd8038cac  rack1
UN  192.168.170.137  518.74 MiB  256          40.9%             b6d61651-7c65-4ac9-a5b3-053c77cfbd37  rack1
UN  192.168.170.138  554.43 MiB  256          38.6%             f1ba3e80-5dac-4a22-9025-85e868685de5  rack1
UN  192.168.170.134  153.76 MiB  256          40.7%             568389b3-304b-4d8f-ae71-58eb2a55601c  rack1
UN  192.168.170.135  350.76 MiB  256          38.7%             1a7d557b-8270-4181-957b-98f6e2945fd8  rack1
```

```
CREATE KEYSPACE grudb WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '3', 'dc2': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

That's my setting.

CL IS ONE.

Comment: Are these physical servers or vms? If VMS, are they on the same ESX host (or host depending on what you're running)? If they're VMS check the host(s) they're running on to ensure you're not overwhelming them. Might also want to consider LOCAL_ONE instead of ONE, but either way, it's not a large number. Is the stress reads, writes, or both? Might want to check resource consumption on each node as well (cpu, i/o, etc.).

Comment: I using cassandra-stress reads, writes both. and JDBC result is like cassandra-stress 10 nodes is slower than node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a 10-node cluster can sustain a higher **throughput**, but whether or not this actually translates to higher "cassandra-stress" scores, depends on what exactly you're doing:

First, you need to ensure that the cassandra-stress **client** is not your bottleneck. For example if the machine running cassandra-stress is at 100% CPU or network utilization, you will never get a better score even if you have 100 server nodes.

Second, you need to ensure that cassandra-stress's **concurrency** is high enough. In the extreme case, if cassandra-stress sends just one request after another, all you're doing is measuring *latency*, not *throughput*. Moreover, it doesn't help if you have 100 nodes if you only send one request at a time to one them. So please try increase cassandra-stress's concurrency to see if that makes any difference.

Now that we got the potential cassandra-stress issues out of the way, let's look at the server. You didn't simply increase your cluster from 1 node to 10 nodes. If you just did that, you'd rightly be surprised if performance didn't increase. But you did something else: You increased to 10 nodes, but also greatly increased the work of **writes** - in your setup each write needs to go to 5 nodes (!), 3 on one DC and 2 on the other (those are the RFs you configured). So even in the best case, you can't expect write throughput to be more than twice better on this cluster than a single node. Actually, because of all the overhead of this replication, you'll expect even less than twice the performance - so having similar performance is not surprising.

The above estimate was for write performance. For read performance, since you said you're using CL=ONE (you can use CL=LOCAL_ONE, by the way), read throughput should indeed scale linearly with the cluster's size. If it does not, I am guessing you have a problem with the setup like I described above (client bottlenecked or using too little concurrency).

Please try to run read and write benchmarks separately to better understand which of them is the main scalability problem.